BFS total memory consumption
For a graph with branching factor 12, the goal at depth 6, and each state taking 120 bytes, how much space BFS takes to keep states in its frontier to search the graph? How much space Depth First Search takes in the same case?
is 6^12*120 bytes is correct answer for BFS? and 12*6*120 for DFS?

"is 6^12120 bytes is correct answer for BFS? and 126120 for DFS?" None are correct. "126*120 for DFS" is too off. You can only answer these type of questions with the code. It's pertinent to how it is being implemented. Note that what you ask differs from big O() notations, space complexity, etc.

You don't know whether the goal will be found soon or late: it could be the first node that is found at depth 6, or the last one at that depth. If you use a queue-based algorithm, the queue size will be different depending on exactly when the goal is found.
